# How to match numbers with only one sign + or -, not +- or -+ in python - HackerRank challenge

Tags: regex, python-3.7

I want to match all valid floating point numbers, that start with + or - or ., and have at least one decimal number. I'm having trouble with numbers on the test data that start with +- or -+ as in the example -+4.5, it gets matched but I don't want it.

```py
tests = '''
+4.50
-1.0
.5
-.7
+.4
-+4.5
12.
12.0
somerandom
'''
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[-|+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+')
for match in pattern.finditer(tests):
    print(match)
```

Result :

```py
<re.Match object; span=(1, 6), match='+4.50'>
<re.Match object; span=(7, 11), match='-1.0'>
<re.Match object; span=(12, 14), match='.5'>
<re.Match object; span=(15, 18), match='-.7'>
<re.Match object; span=(19, 22), match='+.4'>
<re.Match object; span=(24, 28), match='+4.5'>
<re.Match object; span=(33, 37), match='12.0'>
```

Comment: Add `^` in the beginning? Btw, `[-|+]` means: `-` or `+` or `|` characters, you don't need `|` in the character set

Comment: I did not understand, could you be more specific ?

Comment: My comment consists of 2 statements, which of those is not clear